# Problem with selecting user id C# SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem with editing and deleting users from a listbox. User add works perfect. The problem is when I click the user in the listbox, it retrieves from the database the username and password but when I modify the username or password textboxes and click update or delete buttons I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UserName' to data type int

So I changed the code to the one that it is now and I get:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

I need to retrieve the user id from the database so I can delete and modify that specific user.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXdBz.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooiP3.png

private void AdaugaUtilizator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Add user button
{
    if (NumeUtilizator.Text != "" && Parola.Text != "")
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Users (username, password, role) values (@username, @password, @role)", con);

        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", NumeUtilizator.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Parola.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", rol);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Utilizatorul a fost adăugat cu succes");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Completează toate câmpurile!");
    }

    NumeUtilizator.Text = "";
    Parola.Text = "";

    fill_listbox();
}   // This works perfectly

private void EditUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Edit user button
{
    if (NumeUtilizator.Text != "" && Parola.Text != "")
    {
        // Getting System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Users SET username = '" + NumeUtilizator.Text + "', password = '" + Parola.Text + "', role = '" + rol + "' WHERE id= '" + Convert.ToInt32(ListaUtilizatori.SelectedItems.ToString()) + "'", con); 
        

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Utilizatorul a fost editat");

        con.Close();

        NumeUtilizator.Text = "";
        Parola.Text = "";

        fill_listbox();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Trebuie selectat un rând pentru editare");
    }
}

private void DeleteUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Delete user button
{
   if (NumeUtilizator.Text != "" & Parola.Text != "")
   {
       int selected_item = Convert.ToInt32(ListaUtilizatori.SelectedItems.ToString()); //ListaUtilizatori = listbox name.

       // Getting: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Users WHERE id = '" + selected_item + "'", con); 

       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();

       MessageBox.Show("Utilizatorul a fost șters");

       NumeUtilizator.Text = "";
       Parola.Text = "";

       fill_listbox();
   }
}
```

Comment: And another one. Never use SQL like that - you INVITE sql injectio nattacks and if that ends up in production code, suing for gross neglect is likely. See, it is not like this is not a known problem for 20 years or so. And NEVER EVER store passwords in the database like that - again, you get sued and "me incompetent to read standard practices" is not a good defence. Salted Hashed Passwords are standard since... what.... 20 years or so again. Also read up on bvasic SQL - you TREAT id's as strings (not good). And learn debugging... al the code is irrelevant. You construct the string parameter...

Comment: ...if you look at it in a debugger you will immediately see the syntax is off.

Comment: It is not in production, is for examples. At first the buttons worked but there was nothing inserted in the database. Now i get errors after i modified code.

Comment: I'd recommend looking integrating a pre-built security provider library for your application; security is very difficult to do correctly and I guarantee any solution you arrive at will not be secure. I also recommend a bit of study on relational database concepts, such as primary/foreign key relationships and normalization. It probably doesn't matter much for a toy application, but it absolutely matters for designing scalable, performant applications.

Comment: Thank you. All i wanted to know is the piece of code that helps me retrieve the id from the database and use it for finding the specific user that is clicked in the listbox so i can edit and delete it, because i can make the buttons work but then it edits and deletes all the records.

Comment: Side point: you should be disposing your connection and command objects with `using`, do *not* cache them. Also avoid `AddWithValue`, specify parameter types and lengths explicitly

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always parametrize your parameters using `SqlParameter` when you're using `SqlCommand`. using `ORM` like `Entity Framework` and `Dapper` is way better than working with `SqlCommand` directly.

For your current code, the Update and Delete will not work because you're using `ListaUtilizatori.SelectedItems.ToString()` as **SelectedItems** is a collection, and when `ToString()` a collection, it would simply returns the collection name. it wouldn't return any items name. So, the proper choice would be `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` to get the current selected.

The other issue in the query is that you're querying by `id` and yet, you didn't provided!. when you're binding the source, ensure that you create a list item and provide the id like this :

```
ListaUtilizatori.Item.Add(new ListItem(username, id));
```

if you do that, then you can retrieve the id by doing `ListaUtilizatori.SelectedValue` cast it to `int` and you are ready to use it.

The last thing, you should always try to apply some of good coding principles such as `DRY`.

```
private void AdaugaUtilizator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Add user button
{
    if (NumeUtilizator.Text != "" && Parola.Text != "")
    {
        try
        {
            var isSuccess = AddNewUser(NumeUtilizator.Text, Parola.Text, rol);
            
            if(isSuccess)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Utilizatorul a fost adăugat cu succes");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed");
                // maybe it's because the user is already existed ?
                // why not check before insert ?
            }
            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            // handle it 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Completează toate câmpurile!");
    }

    Refresh();
} 


private void EditUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Edit user button
{
    if (NumeUtilizator.Text != "" && Parola.Text != "")
    {
        try
        {               
            if(int.TryParse(ListaUtilizatori.SelectedValue.ToString(), out int userId))
            {
                var isSuccess = UpdateUser(userId, NumeUtilizator.Text, Parola.Text, rol);
                
                if(isSuccess)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Utilizatorul a fost editat");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Parsing Failed");              
            }
            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            // handle it 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Trebuie selectat un rând pentru editare");
    }
    
    Refresh();
}

private void DeleteUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Delete user button
{
    if (NumeUtilizator.Text != "" && Parola.Text != "")
    {
        try
        {               
            if(int.TryParse(ListaUtilizatori.SelectedValue.ToString(), out int userId))
            {
                var isSuccess = DeleteUser(userId);
                
                if(isSuccess)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Utilizatorul a fost șters");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed");
                    // maybe user does not exists ?
                }               
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Parsing Failed");              
            }
            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            // handle it 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Trebuie selectat un rând pentru editare");
    }
    
    Refresh();
}

private void Refresh()
{
    NumeUtilizator.Text = "";
    Parola.Text = "";
    fill_listbox();
}



private int ExecuteNonQuery(string query, SqlParameter[] parameters = null)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(query));
    }
    
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        if(parameters != null)
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        
        connection.Open();
        return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }   
}

private bool AddNewUser(string username, string password, string role)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(username));
    }
    
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password));
    }   
    
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(role))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(role));
    }
    
    const string query = "INSERT INTO Users (username, password, role) VALUES (@username, @password, @role)";
    
    var parameters = new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = username },
        new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = password },
        new SqlParameter("@role", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = role }
    };
    
    var result = ExecuteNonQuery(query, parameters);
    
    return result > 0; 
}

private bool UpdateUser(int userId, string username, string password, string role)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(username));
    }
    
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password));
    }   
    
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(role))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(role));
    }
    
    const string query = "UPDATE Users SET username = @username, password = @password, role = @role WHERE id = @id";
    
    var parameters = new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = userId },      
        new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = username },
        new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = password },
        new SqlParameter("@role", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = role }
    };
    
    var result = ExecuteNonQuery(query, parameters);
    
    return result > 0; 
}


private bool DeleteUser(int userId)
{
    const string query = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE id = @id";
    
    var parameters = new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = userId }
    };
    
    var result = ExecuteNonQuery(query, parameters);
    
    return result > 0; 
}
```